# Refer to previous line when iterating through file with Python

Tags: python

I have a loop like the following:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        print line
```

But I don't want to print just the current line with each iteration, I want to also print the previous line like below, but the code doesn't give me what I am looking for:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        previous(f)    #this does not go to the previous line
        print line
        next(f)
        print line
        next(f)
```

Result should be like this:

Input:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Output:

```
line1
line2
line2
line3
```

Comment: You do need to store the `next()` calls in something, `line` won't magically contain the next line each time you call it.

Answer (score 6):

Iterators can only go *forward*, so there is no `previous()` function.

Just store the current line in a variable; it'll be the previous by next iteration:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    previous = next(f)
    for line in f:
        print previous, line
        previous = line
```

Comment: This was something I was trying, but if you do `previous=next(f)` that should store line 2 right? How can I store line 1 when first iterating through?

Comment: @TheNightman: `previous = line`. `line` is the *current line*, it'll be the previous line the next time you use `next()` (directly or by leaving iteration to the `for` loop).