# How to direct this to file

Tags: python-2.7

This is not direting to file p

```
with open('/var/tmp/out3') as f:
       before = collections.deque(maxlen=1)
       for line in f:
          if 'disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c' in line:
                sys.stdout.writelines(before)
          p.write(before)
```

Comment: have you declared `'p'` somewhere in your code? because there's no `p` defined in this code. you may need to declare `'p'` file, something like `with open('/var/tmp/out3') as f:
    with open('p_file.txt', 'w') as p:`...etc

Comment: yes i declared p as a file.

Comment: ok good. your code works for me. what part doesn't work for you? do you get any errors?

Comment: I want to write the output of deque to a file .

Comment: Please check error below:

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not collections.deque

Comment: you haven't assigned any contents to `deque` so `deque` doesn't have an output, instead you assigned `deque` to the variable `before`, and are trying to write the `deque` function to the file, which gives the error. you need to pass an iterable (some kind of `list`-like object to `deque` in the parentheses in this line --> `collections.deque(maxlen=1)`; you've only passed the parameter `maxlen` to `deque`, but it needs a `list` object. What contents does your `deque` contain? so far, it is empty

Comment: Thanks  a lot for helping me.Please check below code.

Comment: Please check below my completed code and suggest me.

Comment: with open('/var/tmp/out3') as f:
...     before = collections.deque(maxlen=1)
...     for line in f:
...             if 'disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c' in line:
...                     sys.stdout.writelines(before)
...             before.append(line)
... 
       0. c0t5000CCA025A1EE6Cd0 <HITACHI-H106030SDSUN300G-A2B0-279.40GB>

Comment: I am getting the output as line but i want to direct output to file.means i want  to direct this to file.

Comment: 0. c0t5000CCA025A1EE6Cd0 <HITACHI-H106030SDSUN300G-A2B0-279.40GB>

Comment: @Downshift,                                                                                                                     I will explain as per my requirement.i want to grep an expression from a file and want one line above that expression to be written to other file.

Comment: Please help to get the code with above requirements

Comment: Please don't put `code` in comments, they don't format very well. Instead, click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45041974/edit) and write your code into the question.

Comment: So you're requirement is while reading `/var/tmp/out3`, find a line containing an expression like `'disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c'`, if that line is found, write the previous line to a file `'p'`?

Comment: yes that correct.i need that requirement.

Comment: I've added  code in an answer, please try it and let me know if it does not meet your requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys

filename = '/var/tmp/out3'
expression = 'disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
with open('p', 'w') as p_file:
    previous = next(f)
    for line in f:
        if expression in line:
            p_file.write(previous)
        previous = line
```

If the `expression` is found, you should find a file `'p'` in your current directory containing the expression.

It worked when I tried it on Python2.7.10. I took the code from this answer [Refer to previous line when iterating through file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896486/1248974).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code worked thanks.But i need output to direct to another file

Comment: my mistake, you are right, I forgot to change the output to direct to the file instead. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please check-mark the answer "Accepted" if it answered your question. Thank you @Ahmed

Comment: i am new to the site where i should check-mark.Please inform.

Comment: That's okay, no worries :) There should be a 'check mark' button you can press on the left side of the answer, check it 'green', look at this: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) thanks

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. And thank you for accepting my answer, Sir. Cheers.